# apply data only from header contains by dynamic

Tags: angular, html-table, ngfor

I am working with a table, where i require to apply the data visibility only available with header contains throw dynamic. how to achieve this?

here is my example:

```
columns = ['name', 'age']; //required fields declared. on change I need to update the data as well
```

html:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let col of columns">{{col}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of data"> 
    <td >{{item.name}}</td> //how to apply from header instead of manual
    <td >{{item.age}}</td> //how to apply from header instead of manual
  </tr>
</table>
```

expecting like :

```
<tr *ngFor="let col of columns"> 
        <td >{{data('col')}</td> //name value  
        <td >{{data('col')}</td> //age value  
      </tr>
    </table>
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xt4dcz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the `columns` too for `td`. And then on each item, you can access the property for the Object like `item[column]`

Give this a try:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let col of columns; let i = index">{{setHeader(col, i)}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of data">
    <td *ngFor="let column of columns">{{item[column]}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```